# How to Remove Microphone Buzz on Lavalier

Tags: audio-recording, adobe-audition

While recording this narration on my lavalier, there is this buzz that is on the end of a lot of speaking points my video. I have tried the noise reduction process and the sound remover, but I'm finding that it removes too much of the high frequency in other speaking parts. Ultimately, it makes the original audio sound very 'robotic' with not enough high frequencies.

The entire clip is about 10 minutes, but I figure that has to be a faster way to remove this buzz.

Here is a copy of the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BPbO8KxSK8p1BJTyzM2dLG0r8ARzgY0Z/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: I can't tell what software you're in from the picture. Can't say I'm really hearing a 'buzz' as such. It feels a bit too ambient & there's some hiss behind it, which ought to be easy to get out with Izotope RX etc, but no 'buzz'. Tested in RX with 'De-reverb' at default settings, cleaned it up right away.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am in Adobe Audition, I'll try that in AA.